# How to know if I have more than one version of a library installed?

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm having [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54677634/1086511) installing `sf` library in R (I'm using Debian 9 and R 3.5.2).

After reading many `issues` pages on github, I wonder if I may have more than one GDAL or GEOS library installed. But how to be sure? How do I access the number of different versions installed from the same package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ldconfig` to find libraries and their respective version numbers. Something like this should work:

```
ldconfig -v | grep [Library Name]
```

If needed run it as root(sudo). Substitute [Library Name] with whatever library you want to look for such as: libgeos/geos/gdal/etc. Alternatively `ldconfig -v | more` and searching through will give you information on all libraries.

This should give you the list of all versions of that specific library. Please read over the [ldconfig manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) to get more information.

You can also use the tools built into `R` to figure this out. [This page from the R manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/installed.packages.html) give a lot of details on how to list out installed packages associated with `R`. From my limited understanding you should be able to, in an `R` console, run the following to figure out installed libraries:

```
installed.packages(lib.loc = NULL, priority = NULL,
                   noCache = FALSE, fields = NULL,
                   subarch = .Platform$r_arch, ...)
```